# Aurelia plugin scoped CSS

Tags: css, aurelia, bulma

I've built an Aurelia plugin and I'm using some styling there. My problem comes when I want to use this plugin in my existing Aurelia app. The styles are imported at the head so all my Aurelia application is using them.

I've seen the Shadow DOM functionality, the problem is I'm using [Bulma](http://bulma.io/) so I need the individual components to get styles from Bulma, but at the same time, I don't want the rest of my Aurelia app to get those styles from Bulma.

I don't know what the best option is, so I'd appreciate some help here.

Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way to have this is to use inline html + css modules. Are you interested in an example? What have you thought of so far?

Comment: what do you mean by using inline HTML? inline styles inside HTML?

Comment: As I per my understand do you want to add **Bulma** css to only selected component right? If so don't add that css link or import in app

Comment: what do you mean @Lakmi

Comment: what I did was, I added `require` in each html page for load css separately in my app initially in app.html added Bootstrap and I change css according to my requirement for that I added separate css and added that css to html with `require`